# Отработка функции без кнопки

Tags: html, javascript

Есть фильтр, в котором скажем 2 поля инпут, пеосле заполнения человек нажимает кнопку, и введённые значения сравниваются с массивом и в зависимости от этого выдаётся результат. Так собственно вопрос - как убрать кнопку, т.е. что бы человеку не надо было бы нажимать кнопку что бы увидеть результат (отработку ф-ции).

Грубо говоря, такой фильтр:

http://jsfiddle.net/a3X7w/

**HTML:**

```
Random value <input type="text" id="val2" /><br />
SELECT
<select id='val1'>
    <option value='100500'>use 100500</option>
    <option value='800'>why not 800</option>
    <option value='777'>i mean 777</option>
</select><br /> 
YESNO1
<input type='radio' name='val3' value='0' />
<input type='radio' name='val3' value='1' />
<br />
YESNO2
<input type='radio' name='val4' value='0' />
<input type='radio' name='val4' value='1' /><br />
<button type="button" id='filterButton'>filter it!</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myvar = [  
    {name:"data1",val1:100500,val2:3,val3:true,val4:false},  
    {name:"data2",val1:800,val2:1,val3:false,val4:false},  
    {name:"data3",val1:777,val2:2,val3:false,val4:true}  
];
   document.getElementById('filterButton').onclick = function(){
        var filter = [];
        filter.push(document.getElementById('val1').options[document.getElementById('val1').selectedIndex].value);
       filter.push(document.getElementById('val2').value);
       filter.push(rbvalue('val3')=='1');
       filter.push(rbvalue('val4')=='1');
        var filtered_data = [];
       var data_accepted = true;
        for(i=0;i<myvar.length;i++){
          data_accepted = true;
          for(j=0;j<filter.length;j++){
            if(filter[j]!=='' && filter[j]!=myvar[i][('val'+(j+1))]){
              data_accepted = false;
            }

          }
        if(data_accepted){
           filtered_data.push(myvar[i]);
        }
   }
       var container = document.getElementById('container');
       container.innerHTML = '';
       for(i=0;i<filtered_data.length;i++){
           container.innerHTML+=filtered_data[i].name+'<br />';
       }
  };

function rbvalue(html_name){
    var undefined,default_value,i,rb_collection = document.getElementsByName(html_name);
    if(rb_collection!==undefined){
        default_value = rb_collection[0].value;
    }
    for(i=0;i<rb_collection.length;i++){
        if(rb_collection[i].checked){
            return rb_collection[i].value;
        }
    }
    return default_value;
}
```

Comment: Событие "change" или "blur" на каждом элементе, вызывающие функцию, в которой происходят расчеты.

Comment: так там собственно только в одном месте - при вызове ф-ции стоит onchange - я его менял, и фильтр вообще переставал работать

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, я не увидел, где вы это сделали. [Смотрите пример][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/a3X7w/3/

Comment: @Deonis ну вы дописали пару строк в конце ф-ции, а не просто onchange поменяли

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, ни в какой функции, я ничего не дописывал. Во-вторых, какой такой "onchange" и где я его должен был менять? В-третьих, если что-то работает не так, как вы хотели, то внятно объясните задачу.

Comment: @Denois сейчас всё работает так, я просто хочу понять как вы этого добились, я так понял вы добавили строки
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".filtering");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].addEventListener("change", showFilters, false);
}

и поменяли    document.getElementById('filterButton').onchange = function(){
на
function showFilters(){
так?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, изначальноб по событию click на кнопке, у вас выполнялась анонимная функция. Теперь этой фунцкии дали имя "showFilters". Ловим событие "change" на всех элементах, которые считаем нужными, и вызываем функцию. А нужным элементы, добавляем общий класс (*можно и другой селектор использовать*).